# ActiveAdmin Customized Filter Using Params and Scopes

Tags: activeadmin

Is it possible to add a customized filter to ActiveAdmin that does additional database lookups? The example is that I am linking to a screen to display users near a given location (i.e. `admin/users?location_id=1234`). I'd like to use `geocoder` to allow filtering for a certain distance form the location.

I'd like something like:

```
filter :location, as: :select, collection: ['10km','20km','30km'], 
  (selection, scope) -> {
    location = Location.find(params[:location_id])
    scope.near(location.address, selection)
  }
```

Any way to do this?

**Note**: I realize this can be done with `scopes`, but I can't combine multiple scopes (and would like the filtering to exist in tandem with a number of other filters).